# Android Facebook login and server side authentication

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, authentication, hapi.js

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the following:

- Android app with a Facebook login
- NodeJS (Hapi.js) server backend

In the past I was using a simple username password system that made it very easy to create a server side session and authenticate server requests (for example: get all users that are within 50 km of me). I removed that system and chose for a Facebook login in the android app because it will help decrease some of the load (for example: we don't need to store our own images...).

The problem is that I am not sure how to handle server side authentication. All GET's, POST's,... can only be done by users that are also logging in on my Android app using the Facebook integration.

I found the following topics already on Stackoverflow:

- [Facebook authentication to my server using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756878/facebook-authentication-to-my-server-using-android)
- [Provide secure Facebook authentication with my Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456829/provide-secure-facebook-authentication-with-my-server)

I just want an updated opinion on the matter, is it secure enough to just send the token to my node server and make a Facebook API call using it to check for a valid authentication?

If there is a better approach please share it! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is secure enough to send Access Token to your server and make an API call to Facebook for validating that Access Token. AFIK this is the Best approach.

Comment: And what If a "hacker" sends his own Facebook token to my server, how do guarantee it came from my android app and nothing else?

Comment: we will be using `httpGetRequest.setHeader("Authorization", accessToken);
  httpGetRequest.setHeader("X-MajorVersion", "1");
  httpGetRequest.setHeader("X-MinorVersion", "0");
  httpGetRequest.setHeader("X-RevisionVersion", "7");
  httpGetRequest.setHeader("X-Platform", "ANDROID");
  httpGetRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  httpGetRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  httpGetRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");` 
so the Hacker might be getting all this data and even if he gets, he needs to be authenticated from Facebook

Comment: If he reverse engineers the app and does find this piece of code can't he just use a token that he generates outside my app? 

"If you are protecting against just a little bit more sophisticated software engineer (who can reverse engineer your application) - it won't be enough. This engineer can extract a private key from your application and use it to sign requests in his application - remote attestation" Wouldn't he be able to just set the headers in your sample and do a successful request using a token generated outside your app?

Comment: Basically in case Facebook Login we use 2 kinds of Technique to maintain Security. One is to Link the Facebook to user account(on your server) by server automatically or Prompt the user to Link his account to Facebook. Linking the accounts will provide some more security as user can only know his password to link the account.

Comment: I don't think that creating an extra account with a password is the way to go for my app, that seems like an extra step for the user, an extra step that might drive them away.

Comment: If user already has an account then you might prompt him to link his account to Facebook. If he is a new user let him login with Facebook. Even if Hacker tries to get intrude with his token he might not get other user's data. Instead he will be getting only the data for a new user ryt.

Comment: I am only letting people log in using Facebook, there are no existing accounts. For example I have a rest endpoint that returns all users within 50 km, can't he just spam this endpoint using for example postman using his token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74562/discussion-between-avinash-chowdary-and-jdruwe).